# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) didFinishProcessing:(MyView*)myView; //compiler stops here with error
@end

@interface MyView : MySuperclass {

id<MyViewDelegate> _delegate;       
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MyViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

When I try to compile I get " **expected ')' before MyView** ".
Where is the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `@protocol` add the line `@class MyView`. At that point the compiler doesn't yet know about your `MyView` class.

Comment: great, now I have another question for you. What is the difference between #import "MyView.h" and @class MyView;? 

I thought there is no difference but obviously there is because if I just import the class it doesn't work so I needed the line of code you provided.

Comment: You likely have a circular reference. As the protocol relies on the definition of MyView but MyView relies on the definition of MyViewDelegate it would likely fail. `#import` includes the file as though you copy & pasted it. `@class` is a place holder definition. It says 'trust me this class exists, during linking you'll fine it but for now this is all you need to know'.

Comment: Horatiu, @class just tells the compiler not to pay attention on any error connected to this class. #import imports the contents of the file if they weren't imported yet. In your case you are already in that file - I believe that `#import "MyView.h"` inside "MyView.h" will do nothing...

Answer (score 3):

`MyView` is not recognized by the compiler, which is why it expected a close paren before it. This is because the class is defined below the `MyViewDelegate` protocol, so the compiler has not yet seen it. Add

```
@class MyView;
```

above the protocol declaration to fix it.